# Justify/Align li grid elements

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to justify a list of elements to a checkbox to the right like in the jsFiddle. Is this the best practice on how to do it? Traditionally I've never floated items that were nested in each other, so I wanted to make sure if this is the right way to go about this.

**The Code (https://jsfiddle.net/nmLx1ewu/2/):**

```css
.list-group {
  list-style:none;
  margin-right:10px;
}
li {
  width:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
.items {
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li>
    <div class='items'>
      <label>Toggle me</label>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class='items'>
      <label>Longer text </label>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class='items'>
      <label>short</label>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class='items'>
      <label>hi</label>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class='items'>
      <label>more unjustified</label>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is no strict wrong or right when it comes to layouting with CSS. Does it work for you, and achieve the required look? Then it is probably as close to "right" as it needs to be.

Comment: You can also accomplish this using flexbox: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nmLx1ewu/3/). But your answer is primarily opinion based, as there are many ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Since it's working, I'd almost say this is more for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a easier solution without using `float`.

**The Code (https://jsfiddle.net/nmLx1ewu/4/):**

```css
.list-group {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin-right:10px;
}

li {
  width:calc(50% - 2px);
  display:inline-block;
}
.items {
  text-align:right;
}
.items label, 
.items input {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li>
    <div class='items'>
      <label>Toggle me</label>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class='items'>
      <label>Longer text </label>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class='items'>
      <label>short</label>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class='items'>
      <label>hi</label>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class='items'>
      <label>more unjustified</label>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. The no-float solution helps more because it is not screwing up another section I have after this.